# C API interface for C++ code: Passing opaque pointers directly without wrapping

Tags: c++, c, abi

I am currently designing a C API interface for some C++ codes ( This library is delivered prebuild ).

Up until now whenever I need to pass an object I use the following pattern

public.h

```c
struct Object;

error_code take_object( Object * object );
```

private.h

```cpp
#include<memory>
#include "..."

struct Object {
    std::shared_ptr< InternalObject > mObject;
};
```

impl.cpp

```cpp
#include "public.h"
#include "private.h"

error_code take_object( Object * object ){ /* ... */ };
```

*I've omitted the `extern "C"`,etc boiler plate from the examples

This works fine, other than that I have to usually provide an explicit destructor each time. However this destructor actually has the semantic meaning of both destroying the Object wrapper and the underlying InternalObject ( unless it is also used by another resource )

However I also have objects which are structured as follows

```
struct InteralObjectExtra {
    /* ... */
}

struct InternalObject {
    InternalObjectExtra data;
}
```

I need to expose both structs, however the InternalObjectExtra should not be delete explicitly as it is part of the InternalObject.

I was thinking of the following solution

public.h

```c
struct Object;

#ifdef EXTERNAL
struct ObjectExtra;
#endif

/* ... */
```

private.h

```cpp
struct Object {
    std::shared_ptr< InternalObject > mObject;
};

#ifdef INTERNAL
using ObjectExtra = InteralObjectExtra;
#endif
```

impl.cpp ( illustration purposes only )

```
ObjectExtra * get_extra( Object * object ){
    return &( object->mObject.data );
}
```

But I don't know if this is *safe* ( C ABI and stuff ), I would assume so as only pointer to these classes/structs are passed.

The alternative I can see is abandoning all types and resorting to `void *` ( which I would like to avoid ).

**Questions**

Is my original solution safe?

If not is there a better way other than `void *` or making ObjectExtra a wrapper struct which would then need to be destroyed?

**Edit**

InternalObjectExtra is not always a pure struct but might be a templated type such as `std::vector< int >`

Thus simply writting `struct InternalObjectExtra` in public.h is not an option for these types.

Comment: why not just declare `struct InternalObjectExtra;`?

Comment: I've updated the question. Indeed for simple structs this would work but for templated types this would not ( I believe ) as C does not have templated.

Answer (score -1):

For future reference, the solution I went with:

In order to support any type, template based or not, have a forward declared struct publicly and cast it to the correct type internally.

public:

```c
struct vector_int;
```

private:

```cpp
vector_int * do_nothing(vector_int * in_vector) {
    auto internal_vec = reinterpret_cast <std::vector<int> *>(in_vector);
    // ... actually use the vector, like internal_vec->push_back(1);

    return reinterpret_cast <vector_int *>(internal_vec);
    // internal_vec is already a pointer, its value is an address.
    // and we couldn't return &internal_vec, it's going out of scope so its address isn't useful
}
```

This is similar to the `void *` solution but preserves typing information.

Whenever possible, I still use simpler solutions, for example for `std::vector<int>`, `vector.data()` is better. However, the solution described above is more general and can be applied in case where there isn't a clean C analog for a type.

Comment: `vector_int do_nothing(vector_int)` has a type for its arg, but no variable name.  Perhaps you meant `vector_int do_nothing(vector_int *vec)`?  Because your code makes no sense with an arg of `vector_int vec`.  If you're passing a struct by value, I think you'd need `bit_cast` to type-pun a struct value to a pointer.  Whatever your arg type is, your return value definitely can't be the address of a local var.  Also, you have a mismatch between the declared return type (`vector_int`) and the type in your return expression (``vector_int*`).